# Recorrer Json que esta dentro de un array con each de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ayuda por favor como recorro este array con each de jquery (lo que imprimo es el console.log de la variable de entrada datos):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

```
function crearTabla(datos){
$.each(datos, function(i,item){
                    console.log(item);
                    var index=parseInt(i);
                    index++;
                    var tr= $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(index),
                                $('<td class="codigo">').html(item['id']),
                                $('<td class="descripcion">').html(item['descripcion']),
                                $('<td>').append('<input type="button" class="abrirModal btnVer" value="Edit">'));
                            $('tbody').append(tr);

            });

}
```

Comment: No veo nada de malo con tu codigo.  Tienes algun error?

Comment: `var datos = ...` ...  `crearTabla(datos);`

Comment: gracias por la respuesta: cuando imprimo esto:  console.log(item['id']); me devuelve: undefined, e igual no agrega los elementos a la tabla

Comment: esto es lo que imprime el parametro de entrada  datos: {…}
​
data: […]
​​
0: Object { id: "0", descripcion: "arroz", stock: "5.00" }
​​
1: Object { id: "12", descripcion: "yogu", stock: "560.00" }
​​
2: Object { id: "10", descripcion: "chicles", stock: "90.00" }
​​
3: Object { id: "6", descripcion: "chupetes", stock: "20.00" }
​​
4: Object { id: "8", descripcion: "cigarrillos", stock: "30.00" }
​
length: 20
​​
__proto__: Array []
​
__proto__: Object { … }

Comment: agrega el código donde recibis el json

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la variable que recibe tu función tiene la siguiente estructura:

1. `datos` es un object que tiene una propiedad llamada data
2. `data` es una propiedad de datos, el cual es un arreglo (Array)

Me parece que la forma correcta de ejecutar tu función sería

```
$.each(datos.data, function(idx, el) { console.log(el); });
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var datos = {
 data: [
  {id: 0, descripcion: 'arroz'},
  {id: 1, descripcion: 'maiz'},
  {id: 2, descripcion: 'lechuga'},
  {id: 3, descripcion: 'tomate'},
 ]
};

$.each(datos.data, function(idx, el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```